# custom 404 page htaccess without redirect

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a particular routing system:

**index.php**

```
<?php 

// template start include

if(!empty($_GET['page'])){
    $path = "pages/".$_GET['page']."/index.php";
    if(file_exists($path)){
        include $path;
    }else{
        ob_end_clean();
        header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
        exit();
    }
}

// template end include
?>
```

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA,B]
```

That means:
if a user go to https://example.com/account/

the content is taken from **/myserver/mysite/pages/account/index.php**

or

If a user go to https://example.com/pagethatnotexists/

a "standard" 404 error will be shown.

---

I made a custom 404 php page on: /myserver/mysite/404.php

and what I need is to show my custom 404 page without redirect the user. The URL should be always https://example.com/pagethatnotexists/

I know what you think, I could include this page on the else clause in my index page, but the 'template start' and 'template end' will be shown, and I don't want this.

---

I tried adding this line on the .htaccess:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /myserver/mysite/404.php
```

but the user will be redirect to this url

I tried with this line in before and after my rewriteRule

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}/mysite/404.php
```

But I always see the 404 page even if the page exist.

How can I do this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think you can do this from htaccess because you already have a `RewriteRule` that rewrites all not-found pages `!-f` and dirs `!-d` to your index.php file and it even overrides the `errorDocuments` directive .so there is nothing you can do to handle this from htaccess.

Comment: `RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}/mysite/404.php` this makes it so that, every page shows 404.php :) Remove it. `ErrorDocument 404 /myserver/mysite/404.php` should be enough to show custom 404.